# Check if new record added to MySql

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, xcode

I have an app build on Xcode using objective-c, in this app users can post topics and those topics will be loaded in a UITableView from MySql via PHP file.

Is it possible to check if any user posted a new topic? if yes, please direct me how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I did not , i have no background even how to start

Comment: So you need to hire a MySQL person to set up the database and queries.  Which you will call from XCode with NSURL.... then get the output and display as needed in the app. No free work provided on Stackoverflow.com. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the last topic id, then use it  in `WHERE` condition

something like this:

1) fetch results

2) last_topic = results.topic_id

3) fetch results where topic_id > last_topic